# PHP trying to use an a tag to link a php variable to a php script

Tags: php, html

I am trying to work on a page where after the user successfully logs in, their username which is assigned from `$_SESSION` to be used as a link to another PHP page.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    print 'Welcome <a href="user.php">$_SESSION["user_name"]</a>';
} else {
    changePage("login");
}
```

I got it mostly working (it redirects), but I can't seem to figure out the session variable and how to pull the variable in to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use double quotes `"` you can do string interpolation and do quite cool things with curly braces `{}`

```
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    echo "Welcome <a href='user.php'>{$_SESSION["user_name"]}</a>";
} else {
    changePage("login");
}
```

*Note that I swap the `"` for `'` in `'user.php'`

I've used `echo` above but I believe it is the same as `print`, it's the double quotes that are important.

Another option using single quotes would be [concatenation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) which is a fancy way of saying join various bits together. In that case, I would write it as so:

```
print 'Welcome <a href="user.php">' . $_SESSION["user_name"] . '</a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Stop working with different quotation marks in your code. Just write clean code. There are plenty of solutions ...

```
echo 'Welcome <a href="user.php">' . $_SESSION['user_name'] . '</a>';
```

or ...

```
echo sprintf(
    'Welcome <a href="user.php">%s</a>',
    $_SESSION['user_name']
);
```

... just to name a few ...